# Read a blank column in a CSV file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, blank-line

One line of the CSV is:

```
550012207,1,,,Y,,,,,Y,,
```

I'm doing:

```
product_id_a = data_values[0]
quantity_a = data_values[1]
product_id_b = data_values[5]
```

Each line is a scenario to put an order through, and some scenarios call for two products to be added to a cart. My problem is when there is only one item and column 5 is left blank.

I originally wrote:

```
if product_id_b == '' || ' '
   do nothing
else
  code to navigate to second product
end
```

I used `'' || ' '` to try either one because when I tried them separately it ignores the `if` and does the `else`. I then wrote this just to double check:

```
if product_id_b == ' '
    puts '1'
  elsif product_id_b == ''
    puts '2'
  elsif product_id_b != '' || ' '
    puts 'nothing'
  end
```

And it puts "nothing", so I have no idea what the value is. When I do:

```
  puts product_id_a
  puts product_id_b
  puts quantity_a
```

It outputs

```
 550012207, , 1
```

How do I identify this unknown value?

Comment: How are you reading the CSV file, and parsing the lines? This is a common problem when people ignore the built-in [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class and try to roll their own. We need a minimal example of your code demonstrating how you're reading/parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've used `CSV.parse` for parsing (I hope you do), you could mention that empty fields will be parsed as `nil`s:

```
CSV.parse('550012207,1,,,Y,,,,,Y,,')
# => [["550012207", "1", nil, nil, "Y", nil, nil, nil, nil, "Y", nil, nil]]
```

Solution: `ActiveSupport` library (and Rails) gives us very handy method: `.blank?`, you may use it to test if some value is blank: empty, consists only from spaces or nil.

```
''.blank? # => true
'    '.blank? # => true
nil.blank? # => true
5.blank?   # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `p product_id_b` to print the value in an easy-to-read form. `p` is better than `puts` for that purpose.  Also do `p product_id_b.class` to check if it's a `nil` object.